# Can you point me some Sutras on Buddhist Cosmology?

Tags: theravada, reference-request, texts, sutras, buddhist-cosmology

Can someone point me some good sutras for Buddhist Cosmology. I'm interested in the Theravada school's teaching on this.

Answer (score 3):

- [Kosala Sutta 1](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/16.15-Kosala-S-1-a10.29-piya.pdf)
- [Aggañña Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/2.19-Agganna-S-d27-piya.pdf)
- [Cakka,vatti Siha,nāda Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/36.10-Cakkavatti-Sihanada-S-d26-piya.pdf)
- [Satta Suriya Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/47.8-Satta-Suriya-S-a7.62-piya.pdf)
- [Pāṭika Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/dn24)
- [Saṅ­khā­ru­papat­ti­ Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/pi/mn120)
- [Brahma,jala Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/25.2-Brahmajala-S-d01-piya.pdf) Also see for introduction: [An Introduction to the Brahma,jāla Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/25.1-Brahmajala-S-Intro-piya.pdf)

Also Abhidhamma books contain a lot on this subject.

Comment: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.029.than.html another link for the Kosala Sutra.

Comment: Thank you very much Suminda, I should tell you that you have helped me to provide another article on my blog with this answer that will be read by few 100 a day. So thanks agian and i share the good karma with you. Namo Buddhaya!

Comment: Great that it helped.